# Rename [forza] to [forza-motorsport]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I propose renaming the tags for the Forza Motorsport games from [forza](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza) to [forza-motorsport](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport). This would help prevent confusion with [forza-horizon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon).

- [forza-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-3) -> [forza-motorsport-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-3)
- [forza-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-4) -> [forza-motorsport-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-4)
- [forza-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-5) -> [forza-motorsport-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-5)
- [forza-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-6) -> [forza-motorsport-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the following:

- [forza-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-3) → [forza-motorsport-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-3)

  - Made [forza-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-3) a synonym.
- [forza-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-4) → [forza-motorsport-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-4)

  - Made [forza-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-4) a synonym.
- [forza-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-5) → [forza-motorsport-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-5)

  - Made [forza-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-5) a synonym.
- [forza-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-6) → [forza-motorsport-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-motorsport-6)

  - Made [forza-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-6) a synonym.